# fix deleted oauth credential used in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-workspace-add-ons

I accidentally deleted the OAuth credential used in my Google Apps Script Addon. Now I see a `deleted_client` error when I try to test and authorize my addon.

is there any way to fix this?

I don't see a way to create a new Credential, or a way to specify which credential my Add-On should use.

Comment: What do you mean by "the OAuth credential used in my Google Apps Script Addon"? Are you talking about the OAuth consent screen?

Comment: The solution is to create a new OAuth Client and use the new client ID and secret.

Comment: Would you mind providing more details about this? Do you still have the GCP project associated with this add-on? How are you trying to create the credentials?

Comment: I've only deleted the OAuth credential, the project still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Support helped me answer this:

1. Create or get a different project's ID
2. Go to the Script's Project Settings page
3. Enter the new Project ID under the "Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project" section and click "Change Project"
4. Enter the original GCP Project ID and click "Change Project" again
5. The automatically provisioned credential should now be recreated!

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you should do is to review that the Cloud Project linked to your add-on still exists. If it was recently deleted you should be able to recover it. See https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#restoring_a_project for the official instructions.

If you are not able to restore the Cloud project, you will have to create a new one.

The next thing will be to review the set / review the OAuth consent screen.